# React Navigation trying to use navigation.navigate in a class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to access the navigate prop in a class component to navigate to another page however that's not possible outside a functional component. And I'm having trouble trying to use the workaround from the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation).

Current code is just returning an error [image: console error]

I have a feeling I am just misunderstanding the docs in this case. Any help would be huge!

##### Class Component

```
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Divider,
  HStack,
  Heading,
  ScrollView,
  Spinner,
  Text,
} from "native-base";
import React from "react";

const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

function getIsQuestCompleted(querySnapshot: any) {
  return querySnapshot.get("key");
}

class TaskTrackingComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    savedKey: [],
    ttrkerData: [],
    loading: true,

  };

  getTarkovTrackerData = async () => {
    await fetch("https://tarkovtracker.io/api/v2/progress", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.savedKey}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) =>
        this.setState({
          ttrkerData: data,
          loading: false,
        })
      );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("UserApiKeys")
      .doc(user?.uid)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => getIsQuestCompleted(querySnapshot))
      .then((savedKey) => {
        console.log("Saved Key", savedKey),
          this.setState({
            savedKey,
          }),
          this.getTarkovTrackerData();
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    console.log("savedKey state:", this.state.savedKey);
    console.log("Tarkov Tracker Data state:", this.state.ttrkerData);
    console.log("Loading?", this.state.loading);
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Box justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
          <Heading fontWeight={"extrabold"}>Tarkov Tracker Stats</Heading>
        </Box>
        <Divider />
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <HStack space={2} justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
            <Box>
              <Text>Getting Stats</Text>
            </Box>
            <Box>
              <Spinner color="warning.500" />
            </Box>
          </HStack>
        ) : (
          <Box justifyContent={"center"} alignItems={"center"}>
            <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigation("Home")}></Button>
          </Box>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default function TaskTracking(props: any) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return <TaskTrackingComp {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a mistake on my part I did not realise the export was a default and that was causing the error!

Answer (score 0):

try changing onPress function of `Button` to this `navigation.navigate("Home")`

Comment: I appreciate the speedy response however it's okay now!